# How does Hibernate Session handle concurrency performance

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I am quite new with Hibernate and I have this caching handling on hibernate question which I couldn't find the answer.

For instance, Thread A read data from DB, and keep it in first level cache which is bond with Session A, then Thread A sleep for a few seconds. In the meanwhile, another Thread B modified the related data in DB before Thread A woke up. Then, what will happen to the data Thread A retrieved, is it the data before Thread B modified or the data after Thread B modified?

Then what will happen if data is saved in second level cache, will that make differences on data integration?

Comment: This scenario is called 'Inconsistent Read'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, what will happen to the data Thread A retrieved, is it the data
>   before Thread B modified or the data after Thread B modified?

Thread A will still have only the old data. Because, `each session` has its `own first level cache`. To get the updated data `session` can either call `evict(..)` and `load` it again  or call the `refresh(...)` method assuming thread B has saved the data to the DB.

> Then what will happen if data is saved in second level cache, will
>   that make differences on data integration?

The behavior is same as above. Apart from that, if you are having `version` attribute set in the `Entity` you can also use `session.lock(...)` to detect entity changes. For ex: `LockMode.READ` checks the `version` attribute against the database to detect any changes to it i.e., by pass second level cache as well.

Answer (score 2):

"Thread A" will see old data till it reads again from DB.